# Can we implement live audio streaming functionality using tokbox

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I am having a requirement to broadcast live audio on my website.

Scenarios are:

1. One user will talk/sing in my application (only audio) and
2. His followers will have to listen that live audio instantly in the same application(followers can listen only).
3. After broadcasting live audio the followers may give replay through chat.

Can we implement the above scenario using Tokbox?

Note: I am developing my web application in ASP.Net MVC5  +  WEB API.

Comment: You could also do that with [Agora.io](https://agora.io) for free up to like 10k minutes per month or so. Here's a demo on [Github](https://github.com/AgoraIO/OpenLive-Voice-Only-iOS).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with TokBox.

1. Use `OT.initPublisher({ videoSource: null })` to publish audio only. See https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/audio-video/js/#voice And for singing you may want to tune the audio quality, see https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/audio-video/js/#audio-tuning
2. Subscribing to this stream will allow your users to listen to the live audio
3. You will be able access the audio by creating an audio-only archive. The TokBox API provides the audio-only archive for you but you will have to integrate a playback system into your chat system yourself. See https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/archiving/